# AppleScript read and trigger other script base on received notification

Tags: applescript, notifications

Is they a way to read macOS Catalina notification from AppleScript?

it's seems that they are not longer stored with ~/Library/Application Support/ , I'm not even sure of the process name, "Notification Center" seems to failed

I would like to run an AppleScript which can detect and read new notification then trigger other script based on the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following AppleScript code should work if you save it as a “stay open” application.  Just set the property values for `scriptToRun` and `lookForThisText` and it should be good to go.

Don’t forget to grant permissions in System Preferences for your new stay open application to control your computer

```
property scriptToRun : (path to desktop as text) & "your.scpt" -- your path to .scpt file
property lookForThisText : "Search For This Text In Notification Windows" -- your search term
property theseTitles : {}

on idle
    getNotificationTitles()
    delay 0.1
    if theseTitles contains lookForThisText then
        ---------------------------------------------------------------
        delay 6 -- Gives Banner Time To Self Close
        --tell current application to beep 5 -- Just For Testing
        run script alias scriptToRun
        ---------------------------------------------------------------
    end if
    return 1 -- in seconds
end idle

on quit
    --  Executed when the script quits
    continue quit -- allows the script to quit
end quit

on getNotificationTitles()
    -- This Gets The Titles Of The Currently Displaying Notification Alerts And Banners
    tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
        tell (the first process whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.notificationcenterui")
            set theseWindows to every window whose subrole is ¬
                "AXNotificationCenterAlert" or subrole is "AXNotificationCenterBanner"
            set theseTitles to {}
            repeat with thisWindow in theseWindows
                set titleText to the value of static text 1 of thisWindow
                set the end of theseTitles to titleText
                set subTitleText to the value of static text 1 of scroll area 1 of thisWindow
                set the end of theseTitles to subTitleText
                set notificationText to the value of static text 2 of scroll area 1 of thisWindow
                set the end of theseTitles to notificationText
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end getNotificationTitles
```

---

Here is a quick animation showing the process in action.  I created an AppleScript app named Test Notification.app whose only purpose is to display a notification… `display notification "Blah" with title "BLAH BLAH" subtitle "DUH”` Then, using the code I used as the answer to this post, I created a “Stay Open Application”, whose only purpose is to monitor all incoming notification windows for the text in which I define in the variable `lookForThisText`.  Once the text is identified, it triggers another script "Merge Every Finder Window.scpt" which as the name says… merges every Finder window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at it but I always get an error (-> error number -1728 from process "Notification Center") but I'm nearly sure it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why all the `try` blocks ?  They're unnecessary, it's lazy, and it's setting a bad example.  And ***NO!*** to an infinite `repeat` loop.  Never, ever.  Thing is, I know you know all this, so that makes this script even more peculiar.  I hope you'll consider revising the script, particularly the `repeat` loop.

Comment: @Kevin No, you're not doing it wrong.  The script is wrong.  In the `en_GB` locale, at least, the name of the process should be _"NoficationCenter"_ (which is one word).  However, this will vary by locale, and your best bet is to reference the process like so: `tell app id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to tell the first process whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.notificationcenterui" to...`.  The bundle identifier will always be the same across the world, so that should get you the correct targeting reference.  I wouldn't use this script if I were you, however (at least until it's amended).

Comment: OK guys my revised answer should be able to withstand scrutinizing now LOL

Comment: Thank a lot, that work fine, I'm going off-topic but I changed the scriptToRun path to "property scriptToRun : "/Users/myusername/cloud/AppleScript/scripts/demo.scpt"" and I keep getting an error "scriptToRun is not defined" which I don't understand, when I run the same demo.scpt with the same path in a new code, it's work just fine