# Trigger script upon Notification

Tags: notifications

Does anyone know of any way - either OS native or via 3rd-party software - to run a shell command or Applescript when a certain notification is received?

I'd like to run a shell script when Microsoft Teams - and potentially other applications - raises a system notification (e.g. when an incoming call is received).

Comment: This is a negative: If KeyboardMaestro can't do it, then nothing can. This is an old forum post https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/possible-for-notification-windows-to-trigger-macro/2056 but I don't think anything has changed.

Comment: Perhaps you can: Have you read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402539/applescript-read-and-trigger-other-script-base-on-received-notification?rq=1 ?